# CSS pseudo-classes

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, maybe it's obvious, but I couldn't find any answers how to do this.

I have a structure like this on my website:

```
<div class="row-even">
     <article class="featured-job">a</article>
</div>
<div class="row-odd">
     <article class="featured-job">b</article>
</div>
<div class="row-even">
     <article class="regular-job">a</article>
</div>
<div class="row-odd">
     <article class="regular-job">b</article>
</div>
<div class="row-even">
     <article class="regular-job">c</article>
</div>
```

This tiny thing is generated by PHP for listing some articles from two types, a Featured job, and a Regular job. I want to separate these two content types by adding a margin-top for the first one of the *.regular-job* articles. I tried using *first-line*, *first-child*, *first-of-type*, all from the *first-** and even tried *nth-child*, but nothing worked for me.
(I know these separators working on the parent of the element I am using on.)

Is there any way it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sven says, the problem is that you need the elements to be siblings for this selectors to work.

Set a class in the parent, matching the one of the child:

HTML

```
<div class="row-even featured-father">
     <article class="featured-job">a</article>
</div>
<div class="row-odd featured-father">
     <article class="featured-job">b</article>
</div>
<div class="row-even regular-father">
     <article class="regular-job">a</article>
</div>
<div class="row-odd regular-father">
     <article class="regular-job">b</article>
</div>
<div class="row-even  regular-father">
     <article class="regular-job">c</article>
</div>
```

Then, it is easy to set the CSS. for instance:

```
.featured-father + .regular-father article {
    background-color: red;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sU5YQ/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and of course thanks for Sven! It's a shame CSS doesn't support these kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with first-child and `regular-job` is that the articles are not directly in the same parent because they are nested in `row-even` & `row-odd`. You either could wrap the `regular-job` rows in another `div` which gets the margin applied or add another class to the first row containing a `regular-job`. You could even add a class directly to the first `regular-job`.

I don't know how you PHP loop looks like, but maybe try to use a counter for that matter.

If needed I will gladly provide an HTMl/CSS example!

Comment: There is a form where you can select whether the post is a _Regular job_ or a _Featured job_, so if the post has been written the newest post will go for the very top of the block. So if you send in a form with a _Regular job_ content type, it will pop up (in this case) at the third place of the code. (It will be the first of the regular-job classes.) Because of this I can't simply add a direct class for the first regular-job.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to do someting like that:

```
div:first-child .regular-job {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

You select the first parent element that has the child of .featured-job.

PS. Be careful where you are applying the margin, it won't work on inline elements or if you want to separate the parent elements then applying it to the article is not a good idea.

Comment: What if the first div doesn't contain a `.regular-job`?

Comment: @Mathias Then use `div:first-child > div { margin-top: 20px; }`. Even better: assign a top padding of 20px for the first occurring div — also mitigates the issue when [vertical margins may collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

Comment: @Terry But he wants the first div containing a `.regular-job` not the first div containing any div and not the first div if it contains a .regular.job`. Which is impossible to do with pure CSS?

Comment: @Mathias You are right, downvote me pls. Who voted me in the first place?

Answer (score -2):

while iterating in the PHP, add another dummy class with index.
Then it will be a piece of cake to make your custom class:

```
<div class="row-even featured_1">
     <article class="featured-job">a</article>
</div>
<div class="row-odd featured_2">
     <article class="featured-job">b</article>
</div>
<div class="row-even regular_1">
     <article class="regular-job">a</article>
</div>
<div class="row-odd regular_2">
     <article class="regular-job">b</article>
</div>
<div class="row-even regular_3">
     <article class="regular-job">c</article>
</div>
```

notice the two introduced classes: featured_X and regular_X.

then:

```
.regular_1{
margin-top:50px;
}
```

Comment: Apologies but, I would really advise against programming like this. Hard to maintain and unsemantic. It's a quick fix way of programming.

Comment: Ок, everybody has its own vision about things. But my opinion is that this is the most easiest and straight-forward way to do this. This will work 9.9999% of all browsers. Don't thing its TOO hard to maintain. Otherwise, having a complex CSS rule might cause sleepless nights debugging why nothing happens on IE7, for example

Comment: The modified solution: to check the change from featured and regular in PHP and to add additional class only when necessary.

Comment: Classes have nothing to do with semantics. As long as the appropriate HTML elements are used, this shouldn't be a problem. I could imagine a scenario where the margin top declaration for that element comes from a utility class like that is easy to understand, like `margin-top-single`. That would be a totally acceptable way to solve this.

Comment: @GRSEV I respect that everyone has different views on tackling, I'll remove my down-vote & I didn't mean to offend. Although how Sven mentions it with cleaner class names, I agree with that =]